# Adding row to a table in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried searching for this exact scenario, but had no luck.

I want to add a row to a table in Microsoft SQL via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

The table name is `dbo.BlockedEmails` and the column within it that I want to add the row to is `Email`.

There are other columns in the table such as `Timestamp` and `Source`, but I am hoping that those columns are filled automatically or are unnecessary.

Would the correct syntax be:

```
INSERT [INTO] dbo.BlockedEmails [(Email)] blockedEmail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Google has millions of answer for your question.

Comment: Why don't you just consult the [**official MSDN documentation on SQL Server**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) which has **all** the answers for you! Just go look for yourself  - full syntax spec, lots of samples .....

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BlockedEmails(Email)
    VALUES ('blockedEmail@gmail.com');
```

You can also use `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BlockedEmails(Email)
    SELECT 'blockedEmail@gmail.com';
```

Note:  This will only work if all other columns are either NULL-able or have default values.

Comment: Thank you both, unfortunately when I enter it I get the error message: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'dbo.BlockedEmails'

Comment: @brando Probably you're runnig your query while your current database in Management Studio is different from those holding this table. Either use fully qualified table name, including DB name (i.e. `MyDB.dbo.BlockedEmails`) or switch current DB by command `use MyDB` where `MyDB` is name of databesу holding `BlockedEmails` table.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax will be

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BlockedEmails (Email) values (`blockedEmail@gmail.com`)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BlockedEmails (Email) select `blockedEmail@gmail.com`
```

String values should be enclosed in single quotes `'` and also square brackets are redundant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert multiple rows use comma separated

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BlockedEmails (Email) values
('blockedEmail@gmail.com'),
('blockedEmail1@gmail.com'),
('blockedEmail2@gmail.com')
```